# Update sharethis hover widget with new address, title, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharethis, jquery-address

I'm using the sharethis hover widget (display:fixed) together with jQuery Address on an one-page app. All requests are pushState and loaded through ajax. So when a user goes from pageA.html to pageB.html the address is updated through pushState. When i however click on a certain page on "share to facebook", the page where i entered the website is being shared instead of the current one. The phenomenon can be seen on [this website](http://www.posterlion.com).

I've searched in the stWidget object where the url, title, etc is being stored but i can't find it. Sharethis is being really secretive about it and keeps referring to [this page](http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475079-share-properties-and-sharing-custom-information#sthash.fdHmlgu2.gCVBQlcG.dpbs) but that only explains how to activate the widget in the ajax loaded content, not how to update the widget with the new address, title, etc or how to modify it likewise.

Comment: Is the ShareThis code in a different window? (ie iframe)
Or, are your pages being loaded into an iframe and the ShareThis code is "outside" this window?

Comment: The ShareThis code is being loaded through the normal head and i noticed also partly through an iframe. If you inspect the dom you see an iframe is created to f.e http://seg.sharethis.com/getSegment.php?purl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.posterlion.com%2Fposters%2Fpersonalities-posters&jsref=&rnd=1363961293908 I tried to reload the iframe but that didn't help....

Comment: The only option i can see is remove all the button and add them up again through .addEntry() Freaking stupid they're being so secretive like something so simple as updating the variables directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end i made a handler like this. It's stupid though since it removes the buttons and adds them up again instead of just changing the variables. Still i don't understand why they're so secretive about such a simple procedure as refreshing the buttons' vars.

```
function updateShareThisButtons() {

    var services = [];
    services.push("facebook", "googleplus","twitter","pinterest", "email", "sharethis");
    if($('#sthoverbuttons-chicklets').length == 0)
        $('.sthoverbuttons-chicklets').attr('id','sthoverbuttons-chicklets')

    $('#sthoverbuttons-chicklets').html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
          stWidget.addEntry({"service":services[i],"element":document.getElementById('sthoverbuttons-chicklets'),"url":$.address.baseURL(),"title":$.address.title(), "type":"large","summary":"summary"});
    };
}
```